# groovy metaclass replace superclass method

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

Is there a way to replace using the metaclass object, a method that is of a super class.
Example:

```
class A {
    def doIt(){
        two()
        println 'do it!'
    }
    protected two(){   
        println 'two'
    }
}

class B extends A{
    def doLast(){
        doIt()
    }
}

B b = new B();
b.doIt()
/*
 * two
 * doit!
 */
b.metaClass.two = {
    println 'my new two!'
}
b.doIt();
/*
 * my new two!
 * do it!
 */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `two` and `doIt` are declared in the same class, groovy will skip the meta-object protocol for this call.  You can override this behavior by marking the super class as [`GroovyInterceptable`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyInterceptable.html), which forces *all* method calls to go through `invokeMethod`.  For example:

```
class A implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def doIt(){
        two()
        println 'do it!'
    }
    protected two(){   
        println 'two'
    }
}

class B extends A {
    def doLast(){
        doIt()
    }
}

B b = new B()
b.doIt()  // prints two
b.metaClass.two = {
    println 'my new two!'
}
b.doIt() // prints my new two!
```

Comment: mmm ok...the problem is that I want this behavior just for the unit test in a grails application...is there a way to do the same without make the class A implements GroovyInterceptable?

Comment: An alternative is to make B override `doIt` and call `two` itself.  Or create a test specific subclass of B that overrides `two` with standard polymorphism instead of the metaclass.

Comment: mmm sorry the example is not the same situation as I have...I have a class BaseService with the method 'getFileOutputStream' that retrieve a fileoutputstream and create a file, during the test I would like to override it and do a stub method that returns a ByteArrayOutputStream...so I have the subclass (B) that call _two_ itself, now I've solevd it declaring _two_ as a closure instead of a method, but I would prefer declare it as a method